# Как получить число идущее после запятой введённой переменной типа double в C++? (например, ввели 14.25 - вывело 25)

Tags: c++, double

Примерно продумал синтаксис, но выводит число неправильно. Алгоритм такой: число оставить без его целой части, далее умножать на 10 до тех пор, пока разность nmb - (int)nmb не окажется равной нулю.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;

void main()
{
double nmb;

cin >> nmb;

// Кол-во чисел после запятых равно: 

cout << (nmb - (int)nmb) << endl;

// Само число равно

while (nmb - (int)nmb != 0)
{
    cout << nmb << endl;
    nmb *= 10;
}

cout << "Result number is " << nmb << endl;

system("pause");
}
```

---

Мне нужно просто то, что:

1) Убирает лишние цифры/нули (желательно объяснение)

2) Не является чем-либо "заумным" (например, не функции из языка Си)

И ещё нужен тот, кто:

1) Поможет понять причину того, почему у меня код не работает.

2) Тот, кто поправит его, если требуется или подскажет решение моей проблемы.

3) Скажет, есть ли что-то проще ваших Сишных функций: поймите, я новичок.

Comment: `пока разность nmb - (int)nmb не окажется равной нулю.` - этого может не случиться никогда. Почитайте о внутреннем представлении вещественных чисел. Например, здесь: http://www.delphikingdom.com/asp/viewitem.asp?catalogid=374

Comment: Что вы хотите видеть для чисел типа `123495678098765e-40`? 24 нуля, а потом эти цифры?

Comment: Кстати, выделять дробную часть путем приведения к `int` для больших чисел неправильно, поскольку `INT_MAX 2147483647` (а `LLONG_MAX 9223372036854775807`), что недостаточно для больших степеней. Пользуйтесь функцией [floor](https://linux.die.net/man/3/floor)

Answer (score 3):

Скажите, а

```
int nmb, frc;
char dot;

cin >> nmb >> dot >> frc;
```

вас не устроит? После этого то, что вам нужно - будет в `frc`...

Проблема одна - что вы хотите получить для `14.0025` - тоже `25`?

Comment: Это очень хорошее решение, если число получается не в результате присвоения, а  из  потока ввода. Для общего случая, я бы добавил  строковой поток:  double nmb;    cin >> nmb;    int n, frc;    char dot;    stringstream stream;    stream << nmb;    stream >> n >> dot >> frc;  (от меня только плюс)

Comment: Нет: правильный вывод нужен.

Comment: @Novy Что означает "правильный вывод"?

Comment: Ну в случае ввода 14.0025 что-бы вывело не 25, а 0025.

Comment: Тогда предложенный мною метод отлично работает :)

Answer (score 2):

```
int fractional_part_as_int(double number, int number_of_decimal_places) {
    double dummy;
    double frac = modf(number,&dummy);
    return round(frac*pow(10,number_of_decimal_places));
}
```

[c++ convert a fractional part of a number into integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12801062/c-convert-a-fractional-part-of-a-number-into-integer)

Comment: Мне кажется, трудность у автора вопроса как раз c `number_of_decimal_places`.

Comment: Что делает modf()?

Comment: @Novy Возвращает дробную часть числа (см. [std::modf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/modf)). В качестве максимального значения `number_of_decimal_places` можно порекомендовать 15 - максимальное число значащих цифр после запятой для типа `double`.

Comment: У меня трудность как раз с number_of_decimal_places....

Answer (score 1):

```
double nmb; 
// инициализиация  обьекта `nmb`  
std::string s = to_string(nmb);
// удалим последные нули
size_t pos = s.find_last_not_of('0');
s.erase(pos +1);
// вывод дробной части
std::cout << stoi( s.substr(s.find('.') + 1));
```

или просто:

```
string s;
cin >> s;
std::cout << stoi( s.substr(s.find('.') + 1));
```

если нужны все цифры, а не только те, который выдает double по умолчанию

### Дополнение по просьбе автора:

```
cout << (nmb - (int)nmb) << endl;
```

тут мысль у вас правильная, но вы просто выводите значение, а `nmb`  остается  с прежним значением, так как выражение что вы выводите хранится в другой временной переменной(обьекте), которая (ый) уничтожается после вывода. Поэтому результат нужно хранить в каком то обьекте. И, так, как  первоначальное значение `nmb` вам больше не нужно, то можете  хранить в нем, чтобы не обьявить другой обьект.

Теперь про самую главную ошибку:

```
while (nmb - (int)nmb != 0)...
```

Как я описал выше,  `nmb`  не изменил свое значение, и `nmb - (int)nmb` никогда `не будет ноль`, тем более, что вы в цикле умножаете еще на `10`. Или это значение будет всегда ноль, если  дробная часть `nmb`  нулевая. 
 Я напишу, на основе вашего кода, как будет правильно:

```
double nmb;
cin >> nmb;
// получаем дробную часть
nmb -= (int)nmb; // теперь nmb изменил свое значение(убрали целую часть
// хотя я тут еще не учел, что значение nmb может быть отрицательным 
cout << nmb << endl;
// Само число равно
int k = nmb;
while (!k  || k%10 )
{
    nmb *= 10;
    k = nmb;
}  
k = nmb/10;
```

`while (!k || k % 10 )` равносильно выражению

```
while (k == 0  || k % 10 != 0)
```

`условие k == 0`  заставляет умножать на `10` пока `nmb`  не имеет целой части
        `условие k%10 != 0`  заставляет дальше выполнить операцию, пока число не делится на `10`, т.е. пока не дойдем до последных нулей.
     И, так как,  цикл прекращается после того, как число имеет `ноль` в конце, то для получения результата, нужно значение делить на `10` следовательо выводим:

```
cout << "Result number is " << k << endl;
```

Comment: Я кажется непонятно объяснил, что мне требуется...

Comment: Все ясно, ждите ответа, который я добавлю

Comment: @Novy, я с ответом опоздал из за нехватки времени, но постарался  максимально  ответить на ваши вопросы

Comment: Большое спасибо вам: помогли, постарались :) От всей души

Comment: Кстати: выражение cout << nmb - (int)nmb я делал просто что-бы знать, что происходит с числом в цикле.

Comment: это  понятно, что вы  выводите для того, чтобы увидеть, просто  это значение нужно не только  для просмотра, а  для решения задачи.  Надеюсь я смог вам помочь...

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79433/discussion-between-novy-and-ar-hovsepyan).

Comment: Вышло такое дело: программа всёравно не работает. Как работала, так и продолжает... выводить число неправильно. Так что дискуссия продолжаетя.

Comment: у меня работает,  все проверено.  Вы что то не так делаете или не хотите  разобраться

Comment: ..Причём тут разобраться? Код НЕ работает, если вводится 2 и более знаков после запятой. И при вводе 1.1 выводится 2 числа после запятой вместо положенного одного.

Comment: да, извените, была опечатка в условиях. Проверьте, не упустил я еще что? А то, я когда занят, становлюсь невнимательным

Comment: Ничего, бывает. В основном всё то, что я сказал. И ещё кое-что: при вводе 1.456 выводится, как "само число" 4.56 вместо 456.

Comment: все, я скопировал так как у меня записано, чтобы еще раз не ошибаться при работе в двух направлениях.  Но иногда вы тоже пытайтесь найти ошибки- это пойдет вам на пользу

Answer (score -1):

https://ideone.com/Re3Wjx

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cmath>

double a[] = { 1, 12.25, 22.67867897 };
char buf[256];

int main()
{
  for (double x : a)
  {
    for (char *p=buf+sprintf(buf, "%.250f", fmod(x, 1)); *--p=='0'; *p=0);
    if (!buf[2]) buf[2]='0';
    printf("%s\n", buf+2);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Интересно, за что минус влепили...

Comment: я поставил минус, т.к. это ответ ради ответа.

Comment: @goldstar_labs Что вы имеете в виду? Что не хватает пояснений к коду?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, 1) я думаю автор искал что-то наподобие modf, т.е. простое по синтаксису и использованию решение. 2) fmod(x, 1) - это и есть по сути решение, т.к. по определению целая часть числа всегда целая и делится на 1 без остатка (fmod = numer - tquot * denom). 3) Использовать for для совершения преобразований над строкой без самого тела цикла - жуткий говнокод. С моей точки зрения данный ответ только еще больше запутает человека, вместо хоть какой-либо помощи в решении его проблемы,

Comment: данный вопрос задан и оформлен корректно (т.е. не из серии "сделайте мне лабу") и устраивать здесь спец.олимпиаду по нестандартным решениям - не место. Если я кого-то оскорбил, то приношу свои извинения, но все три ответа, кроме содержащего modf получили минус.

Comment: goldstar_labs, это не ответ ради ответа, а ответ ради альтернативного варианта.  Минус ставится, когда ответ не несет пользу, а не  из за того, что автору  не нужен такой ответ или, как думают некоторые,  не предназначен для общего случая.   Ответ также может быть полезным для  частных случаев.  Если вам кажется, что это экзамен на то,  как можно найти недостаток в ответах и в вопросах, то я могу у вас у всех найти  подобные недостатки и  награждать только минусами. Но это не будет полезно для сайта и его пользователей...  Ответ полезен, и  такой ответ может быть и применен кем то

Comment: Эхэм.. Про меня забыли..

Comment: @Novy, а что с тобой?

Comment: Да так... забыли помочь, разговариваете о каких-то виртуальных очках, которые (лично мне) особо не сдались. Есть предложения, как мне сделать свою программу рабочей? Округление может помочь, но это уже отдельная программа. Слышал я про великолепную setprecision, подключаемую через iomanip, но, пользуясь этой функцией, результата не достигается (если через отладчик проверить, то это будет видно). Слышал я ещё вариант с строкой, но пользоваться я ею не умею. Может есть альтернатива?

Comment: @Novy, тебе тут 4 решения предложили - чем конкретно не устраивают?

Comment: Тем, что они все непонятны и запутанны: такому новичку как я это таково.

Comment: @Novy, но ты же ничего по ним не спрашиваешь.